# Looking Up Quotation marks with a array of Strings

Tags: java, string, equals

So I have the following String: dog "and" cat
I split it up into an array named: array1 with,

{'d','o','g',' ','"','c','a',t','"'}

```
boolean works = false;

for (int i=0; i < array1.length;i++){

    if (array1[i].equals("d"){
        if (array1[i+1].equals("o"){
            if(array1[i+2].equals("g"){
               if (array1[i+3].equals(" "){
                  if (array1[i+4].equals("""){ //does work here
                     if (array1[i+5].equals("c"){
                        if (array1[i+6].equals("a"){
                          if (array1[i+7].equals("t"){
                             works = true;
                          }
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
        }
    }
}

System.out.println(works);
```

It doesnt work at the equals with quotations. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Escape the character. And please don't do things like this.

Comment: Escape the " with a backslash: `"\""`

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm#Single_pattern_algorithms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to simplify your code, for example you could write

```
 String s = "dog \"and\" cat";
 boolean works = s.contains("dog \"cat");
```

This makes it much more obvious that works will always be false.

Answer (score 0):

You have ambiguous data types.

I assume that your `array1` is of type `char[]`. If it is, then you should have `==` comparators in your code (note the single quotes 'x' where x is the char you are testing):

```
if (array1[i] == 'd'){
  ....
}
```

if the arrays are of type `String[]`, then you need to escape the " character using a backslash in the comparison:

```
if (array1[i+4].equals("\""){ //does work here
   ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the " character inside the "". Like this:

```
(array1[i+4].equals("\"")
```

Answer (score 0):

`{'d','o','g',' ','"','c','a',t','"'}` this is a char array
you need below code 
You can no equal Char with String.

```
boolean works = false;
for (int i=0; i < array1.length;i++){
if (array1[i]=='d'){
    if (array1[i+1]=='o'){
        if(array1[i+2]=='g'){
           if (array1[i+3]==' '){
              if (array1[i+4]=='"'){ //does work here
                 if (array1[i+5]=='c'){
                    if (array1[i+6]=='a'){
                      if (array1[i+7]=='t'){
                         works = true;`
                      }
                    }
                 }
              }
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean works = false;
String[] pattern = { "d","o","g"," ","\"","c","a","t","\"" };

for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    // Loop over the items in the pattern array, and check if they match array1
    boolean inner = true;
    for (int j = 0; j < pattern.length; j++) {
        if (i + j >= array1.length) {
            // Don't go beyond the end of array1
            break;
        }
        if (!pattern[j].equals(array1[i+j])) {
            // We found an item that doesn't match.
            inner = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (inner) {
        // All items matched
        works = true;
        break;
    }
}

System.out.println(works);
```